# Stop Horizontal Scrolling In Touch Screen Using JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, scroll, touch, touchscreen

I am working on a project that need to scroll using button and not using touch scrolling.

For this purpose, I have used a pure JavaScript code that I am sharing below, but this is stopping all the scrolling even Up / Down too. I just want to stop Horizontal scrolling in touch screen.

I think that it will be done by `offsetX` or `pageX`, but I am not able to mix this with below code. Hoping that you can make this...

```
<script type='text/javascript'>
// Stop Left/Right/Up/Down Scrolling In TouchScreen
window.addEventListener("touchmove", function(event) {
event.preventDefault();
}, false);
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

You could just use CSS to disable horizontal scrolling:

```
div{
  overflow-x: hidden;
}
```